# Limit of increasing sequence of positive measures is again a positive measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(u_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of increasing positive measures on a measurable space. Here increasing means that $u_n(A)\leq u_{n+1} (A)$ for any measurable set $A\subseteq X$.

I am trying to show that the set function $u$ defined on the measure as follows is also a positive measure,$$u (A) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} u_n(A) = \sup u_n(A).$$

My attempt:

Clearly $u(A) \geq 0$ for any measureable $A$. Also it is clear that $u(\emptyset) = 0$ since for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $u_n(\emptyset) = 0$. Now, $u$ is also $\sigma$-additive since,

$$u\big(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\big)= \sup_n u_n\big(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\big) = \sup_n \Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty} u_n(A_i)\leq \Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty} \sup_n u_n(A_i) = \Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty} u(A_i)$$

Also,

$$u\big(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\big)\geq u_n\big(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\big)     ,\forall n \implies u\big(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\big)\geq \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}u_n\big(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\big)= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty}u_n(A_i)      $$

But

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty}u_n(A_i) =\Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty}\lim _nu_n(A_i) = \Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty} u(A_i)$$

These two inequalities show that $u\big(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\big) = \Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty} u(A_i)$. But I have not used that the $(A_i)$are pairwise disjoint, so I think I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine, you have used disjointness in the proof of both inequalities each time you write $u_n(\cup A_i)=\sum_i u_n(A_i)$.

Comment: Completely forgot about that, I knew it when I was writing it up and then got to the end and then thought I never used it. Thanks!